# Problems running Pocketsphinx demo project, segmentation fault?

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, cmusphinx

I'm new here and I hope I could get some help with an Android App using Pocketsphinx (with NDK).

I am doing this work for a school projekt where we are making a GPS and we wanted to add some offline voice recognition, Pocketsphinx seems to be the way to go so I downloaded the libraris sphinxbase and pocketsphinx as well as the demoproject they have.

After quiet a lot of fixing and trying (first of installing and getting used to Ubuntu, fixing errors I got when trying to compile the libraries, errors from trying to build the libraries with the NDK to get the .so file, problems with the project not having right libraries for Android and transforming it to a 2.1 project to test on my phone) I was able to get the program to run(though for some reason I have to lanch it 2 ro 3 times before it shows up on my phone).

My problem appears when I try to use the demo project, for those that don't know how it looks it's just a simple text area and a button, you press the button so it starts recording and then you speak and the inputed speech should appear as text in the area, as soon as I click this button it closes. It doesn't crash, the process dies but I don't get a stacktrace. From what I can see from the debug information it starts the recording process but then crashes after this, my guess is it crashes once it is about to start doing the work with the native code.

What I can understand from the unclear debug information I get is that the Native enviroment is being closed, I get a message from the debug with the tag Zygote and the message being "Process X terminated by signal(11)". From my searching I have learnt that this most likely means a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

This is as far as I have gotten, I have no real understanding of what segmentation fault means or how to resolve this problem. Below I'll add a part of the log, this is what I see before the program dies, if you need anymore information from the logs plese tell me what and how to get it as I am very unsure what information will be helpful.

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10 with Eclipse and the Android pluggins, my phone is a Sony Ericsson Xperia if that's relevant, running some Sony Ericsson version of Android 2.1, the sphinx libraries are the latest version from the Sphinx projects website.

Hope someone here can give me some way to keep working on this, I am mostly a Java developer but I have done some work in C++ so if I have to I'll dig into the C code as well but I hope it won't go that far.

Here is the log extract:

```
03-20 11:37:22.676: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(385): signalling START
03-20 11:37:22.676: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(385): signalled START
03-20 11:37:22.676: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(385): gotSTART
03-20 11:37:22.676: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.RecognizerTask(385): START
03-20 11:37:22.806: D/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxDemo(385): Showing Dialog
03-20 11:37:22.826: I/AudioHardwareQSD(1066): AudioHardware PCM record is going to standby.
03-20 11:37:22.836: I/AudioHardwareQSD(1066): AudioHardware PCM record is going to standby.
03-20 11:37:22.836: D/dalvikvm(385): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'Decoder_startUtt__SWIG_0' (wrong CL)
03-20 11:37:22.836: D/dalvikvm(385): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libexif.so' for 'Decoder_startUtt__SWIG_0' (wrong CL)
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/X10i_1234-9753/X10i/es209ra:2.1-update1/2.1.A.0.435/TP7d:user/release-keys'
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063): pid: 385, tid: 395  >>> edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo <<<
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0000001c
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000154  r3 8c6d703c
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063):  r4 00000000  r5 81356e14  r6 475c8d6c  r7 00000000
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063):  r8 475c8d6c  r9 00000154  10 43117f40  fp 00123e08
03-20 11:37:22.846: I/DEBUG(1063):  ip 8130c191  sp 475c8d18  lr 8130c1a1  pc 8130d568  cpsr 40000030
03-20 11:37:22.866: I/DEBUG(1063):          #00  pc 0000d568  /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so
03-20 11:37:22.866: I/DEBUG(1063):          #01  pc 0000c19c  /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):          #02  pc 0000edb4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): code around pc:
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): 8130d558 447db089 1c0458ab 681b1c0f 93074691 
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): 8130d568 2b0069c3 e0d3d100 36301c06 f0331c30 
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): code around lr:
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): 8130c190 b083b500 21001c10 93019200 f9d6f001 
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): 8130c1a0 bd00b003 b084b510 93019200 23001c10 
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): 8130c1b0 93022400 f0009403 f030fe3b 9903fc47 
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063): stack:
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cd8  7fffffff  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cdc  ab227f0f  /system/lib/libmedia.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8ce0  afe3db7c  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8ce4  afe0f130  /system/lib/libc.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8ce8  afe3db7c  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cec  afe0f130  /system/lib/libc.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cf0  00000000  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cf4  afe0f048  /system/lib/libc.so
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cf8  afe3d9c4  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8cfc  00002004  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d00  00000001  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d04  078bcd20  
03-20 11:37:22.876: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d08  00000209  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d0c  b0000463  /system/bin/linker
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d10  df002777  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d14  e3a070ad  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063): #00 475c8d18  00000000  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d1c  afe0f048  /system/lib/libc.so
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d20  afe3d9c4  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d24  0014bac0  [heap]
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d28  003952b8  [heap]
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d2c  0000a000  [heap]
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d30  ad00ef40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d34  8c6d703c  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d38  0014ba78  [heap]
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d3c  475c8d6c  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d40  43117f54  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d44  475c8d90  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d48  00000004  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d4c  458ad8c8  /mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d50  43117f60  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d54  8130c1a1  /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063): #01 475c8d58  00000000  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d5c  00000000  
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d60  430fdfae  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.apk@classes.dex
03-20 11:37:22.886: I/DEBUG(1063):     475c8d64  ad00edb8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 11:37:23.026: D/Zygote(1065): Process 385 terminated by signal (11)
03-20 11:37:23.056: I/ActivityManager(1140): Process edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo (pid 385) has died.
03-20 11:37:23.056: I/UsageStats(1140): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo
03-20 11:37:23.056: I/WindowManager(1140): WIN DEATH: Window{45f50c48 edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxDemo paused=false}
03-20 11:37:23.086: I/AudioHardwareQSD(1066): AudioHardware PCM record is going to standby.
03-20 11:37:23.116: W/InputManagerService(1140): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 385 uid 10106
```

I have been trying to find an answer and most threads I found asked to look in the log file from the app and those were usually the end of the thread, my project doens't give me a log file (even if the code to create one is there). I am at a loss of where to look next and I hope someone here can give me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is as far as I have gotten, I have no real understanding of what
>   segmentation fault means or how to resolve this problem

If you want to be a software developer you should better learn it in detail. You can find some starting point from Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Usually segmentation fault means there is a bug in your application or configuration

> and most threads I found asked to look in the log file from the app
>   and those were usually the end of the thread, my project doens't give
>   me a log file (even if the code to create on is there)

This is a perfectly valid advice for you too. You need to find out why the file pocketsphinx.log is not being created. It's path is configured in the sources. Most likely it's created on sd card, but you can configure another location. The contents of this log will tell you what is the issue with your application.

Comment: I will read up on segmentation fault and investigate why the log file isn't being created, hopefully I can figure out where the segmentation occurs, is the debug info I recive enough for this?

Comment: current information is not enough. You need to access that log file.

Comment: It seems it wasn't a seg fault at all, but I got the log files (they weren't being made due to the folder structure not being made) and it told me something was wrong with the languge model files, some of the files were empty, recopying these files made it work, thanks for the help.